# OnPropertyChanged and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to specify data variable for my TextBlock at xaml:

```
<TextBlock Name="Test11" Text="{Binding Path=Test}"></TextBlock>
```

I'm using OnPropertyChanged for it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged

private string _test;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                return _test;
            }
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }
```

And trying to set value at MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Test = "teeest";
        }
```

But Textblock.Text wasn't updated...
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the datacontext so the UI knows where to get the data for the binding.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    Test = "teeest";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Window constructor after

> InitializeComponents()

put

`this.DataContext = this;`